# Get Text except specific color from PDF using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

I want to get all Text from the PDF File (specific location from coordinates) except Red Text.
Here is the code that I am using to get text from specific Location on PDF

```
public string ReadTextFromRectangle(string pdfPath, int numberOfPages, float x, float y, float width, float height)
        {
            this.PdfPath = pdfPath;
            this.NumberOfPages = numberOfPages;
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;

            var reader = new PdfReader(PdfPath);

            System.util.RectangleJ customerIdRectangle = new System.util.RectangleJ(X, Y, Width, Height);
            string output = "";

            for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                RenderFilter[] filters = new RenderFilter[1];
                LocationTextExtractionStrategy regionFilter = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                filters[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(customerIdRectangle);
                FilteredTextRenderListener strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(regionFilter, filters);

                try
                {
                    output = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }


            return output;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code you already are half way there!

All you have to do is add another `RenderFilter` to `filters`, one that blocks red text. While such a filter class is not included in the core iText distribution, it is easy to implement yourself:

- implement `AllowImage` to always return `true`;
- implement `AllowText` to check the text color.
  There actually are multiple options here but for starters let's assume the default (*filled* glyph outlines) is used. That means you merely have to retrieve the fill color from the `TextRenderInfo` object using its `GetFillColor` method and check its redness.

Comment: Could you please write a example ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kn1ghtx *"Could you please write a example ?"* - For that please share a representative example PDF to test it with.

Comment: There is a random text with one or two lines with red color!!

Comment: Please share one, though. Sometimes there are detail issues to consider one does not spot without having a common example.